# About Html + javascript in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I want to draw highlight of text.
But, it's very difficult to realize this with UILabel.
So, I'm trying with `UIWebView`.

When I click html, webpage is changed like pic in Web browser.

[image: the result image what I want]

But, `UIWebView` made by this code doesn't work.

My code is :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *var = nil; 
    var = @"<html>"
    "<head>"
    "<script type='text/javascript'>"
    "var ie = document.all"
    "var ns = document.getElementById && !ie"
    "function rowclick(e) {"
    "    var obj = ns ? e.target : event.srcElement"
    "    if (obj.tagName=='TD') {"
    "        obj.style.background='#e6e6e6'"
    "        obj.onblur=function() {"
    "            obj.style.background='#ff0066'"
    "        }"
    "    }"
    "}"
    "document.onclick=rowclick"
    "</script>"
    "</head>"
    "<body>"
    "<table>"
    "<tr height=50><td><a href='#'>test</a></td></tr> <!--doesnt work since i have a <a href> tag -->"
    "<tr height=50><td><a href='#'>test</a></td></tr> <!--doesnt work since i have a <a href> tag -->"
    "<tr height=50><td><a href='#'>test</a></td></tr> <!--doesnt work since i have a <a href> tag -->"
    "<tr height=50><td>test</td></tr>"
    "</table></head></html>"; 

    [self.webView loadHTMLString:var baseURL:nil];


}
```

And I'm setting detection like pic in WebView's inspector.

[image]

Please Could you tell me my code's faults? Thanks !!

Comment: I found good source. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/iPhoneDevReader.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this method can help you:

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! But, my js code is wrong. I used other js code and then success!! thanks!!